# Create array from xml more objects with same name

Tags: php, xml

Is there a way to create an array from xml file that will contain all of the <IMG_ALTERNATIVE> values so I can use them in my other function?
The xml looks like this:

```
<SHOP>
<SHOPITEM>
<ITEM_ID>item id</ITEM_ID>
<SKU>item SKU </SKU>
<PRODUCT>Product name</PRODUCT>
<DESCRIPTION>Item descirption</DESCRIPTION>
<URL>
https://www.itemurl.com/item
</URL>
<IMGURL>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg.jpg
</IMGURL>
<IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg2.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
<IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg3.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
```

I parse the xml this way in php:

```
foreach ($xml as $item) {
            $data[md5($item->URL->__toString())] = ['item_id' => null,
                                'title' => $item->PRODUCT->__toString(),
                                'text' => $item->DESCRIPTION->__toString(),
                                'item_url' => $item->URL->__toString(),
                                'img_url' => $item->IMG_URL->__toString(),
                                'img_alt' => $item->IMG_ALTERNATIVE->__toString()
                                ];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
<?php

$xmlstring = "
<xml>
    <SHOP>
        <SHOPITEM>
            <ITEM_ID>item id</ITEM_ID>
            <SKU>item SKU </SKU>
            <PRODUCT>Product name</PRODUCT>
            <DESCRIPTION>Item descirption</DESCRIPTION>
            <URL>
https://www.itemurl.com/item
</URL>
            <IMGURL>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg.jpg
</IMGURL>
            <IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg2.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
            <IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg3.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
        </SHOPITEM>
    </SHOP>
</xml>
";
$array = array();
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
foreach ($xml->SHOP->SHOPITEM as $element) {
    foreach($element as $key => $val) {
        array_push ( $array,"{$key}: {$val}");
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/0igDF

Answer (score 0):

thought about using a regular expression ?
https://3v4l.org/uatdY

```
$ls = "<SHOP>
<SHOPITEM>
<ITEM_ID>item id</ITEM_ID>
<SKU>item SKU </SKU>
<PRODUCT>Product name</PRODUCT>
<DESCRIPTION>Item descirption</DESCRIPTION>
<URL>
https://www.itemurl.com/item
</URL>
<IMGURL>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg.jpg
</IMGURL>
<IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg2.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
<IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg3.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>";

preg_match_all('/<IMG_ALTERNATIVE>\r?\n(.*)\r?\n<\/IMG_ALTERNATIVE>/', $ls, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg2.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
            [1] => <IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg3.jpg
</IMG_ALTERNATIVE>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg2.jpg
            [1] => https://www.itemurl.com/itemimg3.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: This seems too complicated and I thought there might be an easier way to do it, and also to get it into an one dimensional array. Thank you for your comment tho!